# Why is infinitescroll loading the same images all the time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, infinite-scroll

I have an app set up in Laravel. The app basically plugs into an instagram api library and gets images etc and  allows sharing and liking and all that goes with it.

I am trying to get infinite scroll working on the site, where it loads the next page of images into the page and so on. Currently this is not working at all its just loading the same images each time. I know why it is doing it and this is because the url is always the same in the pagination and it is not being updated each time the images are added.

This is the setup:

JS -

```
$('#images').infinitescroll({
        navSelector     : "#pagination",
        nextSelector    : "#pagination a",
        itemSelector    : ".instagram-image",
        debug           : true,
        prefill: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        appendCallback: false
        // behavior     : 'twitter',
        // appendCallback   : false, // USE FOR PREPENDING
        //pathParse        : function( pathStr, nextPage ){ return pathStr.replace('2', nextPage ); }
    }, function(newElements, data, url){
        //USE FOR PREPENDING
        // $(newElements).css('background-color','#ffef00');
        $(this).prepend(newElements);
        //
        //END OF PREPENDING

//      window.console && console.log('context: ',this);
      window.console && console.log('returned: ', newElements);

    });
```

Markup -

```
echo '<section id="images">';

foreach ( $media as $item ) {

    echo '<article class="instagram-image">';
    // define the form and set the action to POST to send the data to this script
    echo '<form id="'. $token .'" class="forms" action="'; echo URL::current(); echo '" method="post">';

        $id = $item->getId();

        echo '<a title="' . $item->getCaption() .'" class="fancybox" rel="folk-1" href="' . $item->images->standard_resolution->url . '"><img alt="' . $item->getCaption() .'" src="' . $item->images->standard_resolution->url . '" /></a>';
        echo '<div class="formSubmit-feedback"></div>';
        if ( $current_user->likes($item) ){
            echo '<button class="ajax instabtn button-unlike unlike icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Unlike"></button>';
        } else {
            echo '<button class="ajax instabtn button-like like icon-heart" type="submit" name="action" value="Like"></button>';
        }
        echo '<input class="id" type="hidden" name="id" value="'; echo $id; echo '">';

        echo '<p>'; echo $item->likes->count; echo '</p>';

    echo '</form>';
    echo '</article>';
}
echo '</section>';
```

Then this is the pagination markup:

```
<div id="pagination">
    <?php if( $media->getNext() ) { ?>
        <a class="next_id" href="<?php echo URL::current() ?>?max_id=<?php echo $media->getNextMaxId(); ?>" class="next_page">Next page</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

This then renders this in the page:

```
<a class="next_id" href="http://folk:8888/?max_id=588378248253423565_195163470">Next page</a>
```

Everytime it loads the items the url does not change, the next url to the next set of images is basically so this is what would be on the next page:

```
<a class="next_id" href="http://folk:8888/?max_id=556279164512386673_195163470">Next page</a>
```

so getting this is not that easy but also the infinite scroll cannot determine this in the script.

Has anyone got an idea about how this can be setup or a workaround for it?

Any help would be amazing on this,

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

do something like this if i understand you:

change your articles layout and put the article id in id

```
 echo '<article class="instagram-image" id="$article->id">';
```

now in infinite scroll just get the last instagram-image class id like so:

```
last_id = $("div.instagram-image:last").attr('id');
```

now send that id to php with ajax
and in your controller do something like:

```
$last_id=0;
if (Input::has('last_id') $last_id = Input::get('last_id')
```

and your sql like this:

```
$media = Media::where('id','>',$last_id)->take(10);
```

now when you scroll down and the ajax is called the php will return the items after the last one

Comment: Hey Amir, this seems pretty straightforward I think. I will have a go at this and see what results I get. I am not storing any of the images in a database so that sql statement probably wont work. Also how does this get the url from the next page? Like explained above I am trying to get next url to be added to the pagination url? How can the above do this. Please tell me if I am being retarded!